# Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate() with a logical operator in the query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have do do something like this (please forgive me about the stupidity of the example... :-):

```
var dateRef = new Date(1990, 1, 1);
Person.findOneAndUpdate({ dateOfBirth > dateRef }, { $set: { isYoung: true } }, function (err, doc) {
});
```

I.e.: I'd like to $set isYoung field of every Person document to true for all the persons whose date of birth (`dateOfBirth`) is later than a reference date.

My code is syntactically wrong, of course...

So the question is: *is there a method to do what I ask? Id' prefer it to be an atomic (?) operation (as opposite to a for(...) loop...).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) if refering to another field in the document:

```
Person.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "$where": "return this.dateOfBirth > this.dateRef" },
    { "$set": { isYoung: true } },
    { "new": true },
    function (err, doc) {
    }
);
```

And likely `{ "new": true }` if you want to see the modified result rather than the original unmodified document.

The `$where` operator itself allows JavaScript evaluation of conditions within the issued query. It is generally better to issue with other "native" operator conditions as the evaluation itself cannot utilize an index to improve performance.

There is no other way in such an update statement to compare the value of one field against another, unless you call the data back from the server first, but this should be avoided due to possible changes in the document between statements.

But if you want an "external" value from a variable, then just use the native [`$gt`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) operator instead:

```
var date = new Date("1990-01-01");

Person.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "dateOfBirth": { "$gt": date } },
    { "$set": { isYoung: true } },
    { "new": true },
    function (err, doc) {
    }
);
```

MongoDB queries are not SQL statements, and you evaluate values beforehand. As such `$gt` is a "native" operator and what you should be using unless you "really need" to compare fields in a document against each other.

Comment: What do you mean by `to issue with other "native" operator conditions`?

Comment: @MarcoS I think you need to read everything. The difference is between "comparing fields in a document" to "comparing to an external value". In the latter case you generally want to use the native operator such as `$gt`, and preferably in the former case to use such a native operator to filter down possible documents before that condition is applied. For the reason already stated, that JavaScript evaled statements cannot use indexes.

Comment: Sorry... I did post my comment before you did finish your answer... Now it's very clear... :-)

Comment: Probably `findOneAndUpdate()` is not the right method to use, if I have **many** persons matching that criteria, and I want to update all of them at once... :-( I can't find a `findAndUpdate()` or a `findAllAndUpdate()`... :-(

Comment: @MarcoS It's just called `.update()`. But of course there is absolutely no option to "return" the matched document(s) under such as statement by design. Of course if you really think you need to return each modified document, then you are probably better off just doing a `.find()` after that process is complete. They have different purposes.